# Does a Disneyland Resort VIP Tour get you access to Club 33?

Tags: usa, los-angeles, disney

Does a [Disneyland VIP Tour](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/vip-tours/) get you access to [Club 33](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_33)?

Supposedly Club 33 has a membership wait list of 10 years, an initiation fee of $25,000 and annual fees of $10,000, but I figure you'd have to go at least a few times a year to justify that kind of expense and I just want to experience it once.

For upwards of $5,000 / day, Disneyland VIP tours can let you do pretty exclusive stuff as is, like cutting in front of the line for pretty much every ride and what not, so Club 33 admission would be consistent with that but I'm still guessing that Club 33 is still a level of exclusivity that exceeds what Disneyland VIP tours offer.

Comment: How does this relate to Travel as defined in the Help page: _https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic_ ? What is the actual problem to be solved?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica It seems like the OP wants to know if they can purchase this tour and be able to visit Club 33 once. That seems like an actual travel problem to me.

Comment: @Zach Lipton An actual problem, perhaps, but not IMO travel-related. One could live next door to Disneyland and have the same query.

Comment: On rare occasions I have had the opportunity to visit 'exclusive' establishments as the guest of a friend or business associate. The establishments were sumptuous and luxurious, but the principal benefit of membership always appeared to be the bragging rights. No VIP tour will get you $40,000 worth of those.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not address a travel question, but instead a question about access to a member-only establishment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A Resort VIP Tour does not also grant access to Club 33. The only way to use any of the Club 33's worldwide is to:

1. Join Club 33 at the resort of your choice (membership does not grant access to other resorts' Club 33's, either.
2. Find a current member and get them to allow you to use their membership (invite you as an unaccompanied guest) or invite you as an accompanied guest.

That's it.

Comment: Unaccompanied guests are not allowed so the Member would have to invite you to join them.

Comment: As of January 2020, members could still make a limited number of unaccompanied reservations per year. A membership is on the line, however, so most will not be willing to do so.